# Did I correctly translate this pseudocode into Java?

Tags: java, math

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052626/how-to-make-a-circle-within-another-circle?noredirect=1#comment6293284_3052626) on Math.se a few days ago, and got the following answer in pseudocode:

```
Function RandomCircleInside(centerX, centerY, radius):
    Let  newRadius = radius * Random()
    Let  radians = 2.0 * 3.14159265358979323846 * Random()
    Let  deviation = (radius - newRadius) * Sqrt(Random())
    Let  newX = centerX + deviation * Cos(radians)
    Let  newY = centerY + deviation * Sin(radians)
    Return (newX, newY, newRadius)
End Function
```

I changed the pseudocode to Java and added my own changes to fit my needs. The new code looks like this:

```
Circle createNewCircle(int centerX, int centerY, int radius, int newR, Color newColor) {
    int newRadius = radius * Random();
    double radians = 2.0 * 3.141592653589793 * Random();
    double deviation = (radius - newRadius) * Math.sqrt(Random());
    System.out.println(radius + " - " + newRadius + " * sqrt(0 or 1) = " + (radius-newRadius) + " * (0 or 1) = " + deviation);
    double newX = centerX + deviation * Math.cos(radians);
    System.out.println(centerX + " + " + deviation + " * cos(" + radians + ") = " + (centerX + deviation) + " * " + Math.cos(radians));
    double newY = centerY + deviation * Math.sin(radians);
    int newCirX = (int) newX;
    int newCirY = (int) newY;
    Circle newCir = new Circle(newCirX, newCirY, newR*2, newR*2, newR, newColor, true);
    return newCir;
}
```

The code itself is supposed to create a new Circle inside of a preexisting one. I created a circle class that looks like this:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Circle {

    public int X, Y, Width, Height, radius;
    public Color color;
    public boolean toFill;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int width, int height, int radius, Color color, boolean fill) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
        toFill = fill;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        for(int i=-5; i<5; i++) {
            if(toFill) {
                g.fillOval(X+i, Y+i, Width-i, Height-i);
            } else {
                g.drawOval(X+i, Y+i, Width-i, Height-i);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(Circle pBound) {
        int pBoundCenterX = pBound.X+pBound.radius;
        int cirCenterX = X+radius;

        int diffBetweenCentersX = Math.abs(pBoundCenterX-cirCenterX);

        int pBoundCenterY = pBound.Y+pBound.radius;
        int cirCenterY = Y+radius;

        int diffBetweenCentersY = Math.abs(pBoundCenterY-cirCenterY);
        if(diffBetweenCentersX<= (pBound.radius+radius) && diffBetweenCentersX>=Math.abs(pBound.radius-radius)) { // X
            if(diffBetweenCentersY>=Math.abs(pBound.radius-radius)) { // Y
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return X;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return Width;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        Width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return Height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        Height = height;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        X = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return Y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

My way of creating the new circle is this:

```
if(secInGame==timesForCircle[X] && !hasChanged) { // circle 2
    Circle cir1 = cir;
    cir = createNewCircle(cir1.X+(cir1.Width/2), cir1.Y+(cir1.Height/2), cir1.getRadius(), 135, Color.cyan);
    hasChanged = true;
    circleOn++;
    circ++;
}
```

Where `cir1` is the preexisting Circle and `cir` is the new circle.

Is there anything I didn't code correctly? I've tried a few different variations, but they all give the same result.

Before I implemented the pseudocode, my circles looked like this:

[image]

but now it looks like this:

[image]

All of my code can be found on github at: [link](https://github.com/BlazeDaBlur1/Battle-Royale-Safe-Zones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several issues in your code.

**1.** First of all it is not clear why your `Circle` has `radius`, `Width` and `Height`. For a circle all 3 things should be the same. Also your `render` in case `toFill` is `true` looks strange. Here is a simplified version (note: I didn't compile it so there might be some bugs):

```
public class Circle {
    public int X, Y, radius;
    public Color color;
    public boolean toFill;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int radius, Color color, boolean fill) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
        toFill = fill;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        final int r2 = 2*radius;
        if(toFill) {
            g.fillOval(X, Y, r2, r2);           
        }
        else {
            for(int i=-5; i<5; i++) {
                g.drawOval(X+i, Y+i, r2-i, r2-i);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(Circle pBound) {
        int pBoundCenterX = pBound.X+pBound.radius;
        int cirCenterX = X+radius;

        int diffBetweenCentersX = Math.abs(pBoundCenterX-cirCenterX);

        int pBoundCenterY = pBound.Y+pBound.radius;
        int cirCenterY = Y+radius;

        int diffBetweenCentersY = Math.abs(pBoundCenterY-cirCenterY);
        if(diffBetweenCentersX<= (pBound.radius+radius) && diffBetweenCentersX>=Math.abs(pBound.radius-radius)) { // X
            if(diffBetweenCentersY>=Math.abs(pBound.radius-radius)) { // Y
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return X;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        X = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return Y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

I didn't check your code, but I'd consider as a good practice:

- renaming `x` and `y` into `leftX` and `topY` to avoid confusion with `centerX`/`centerY` meaning. Or change meaning to more typical `center` one.
- declaring all your fields as `private` (see [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)));
- declaring all your fields as `final` and remove all the `setXyz` methods (see [immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object))

**2.** I don't understand why your `createNewCircle` has `newR` parameter and at the same time you generate a random `newRadius` in the first line. One of these definitely should be removed. Given that the parameter is always a constant `135` I think it should be removed.

**3.** Now I believe the main bug in your translation is in the lines

```
 int newCirX = (int) newX;
 int newCirY = (int) newY;
```

It probably should be something like

```
 int newCirX = (int) newX - newRadius;
 int newCirY = (int) newY - newRadius;
```

It looks like you messed with center vs top-left. Actually I think the fact that you made such a bug is an argument that supports renaming `x` and `y` I suggested in item #1.